# Intent.putExtra(String,Bundle) vs Intent.putExtra(Bundle)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

This question may sound stupid but I wana know When do we put activity name in `Intent.putExtra()`? In one case we are putting extra only with bundle and in other case we are passing it with class name. I am a little confused should we use `Intent.putExtra(String, Bundle)` we already have passed the activity name in `Intent` constructor or not?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Bundle is used for allocating some space,while we use put extra and get extra Through the bundle(allocated space)only it will transfer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you mean `putExtra(String, Bundle)` vs `putExtras(Bundle)` (with **s**).

The first adds the bundle as the value for the key you provide. The bundle is simple an object value.

The second adds all the key/value pairs from the provided bundle to the intent. In this case the content of the bundle will be added to the intent, not the bundle itself.

Think of them as in `Map` interface:

```
Map.put(String key, Object value)
```

vs

```
Map.putAll(Map anotherMap)
```

Answer (score 5):

The approach is just the difference here. If you use a `Bundle` you can store almost all types in it:

```
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.put(key, value);
```

and pass it to an activity

```
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

and in the other activity which recieves the info, just grab the content of the bundle like  this:

```
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

and grab each element in the `bundle` like this:

```
extras.getString("myKey")
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at source code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/content/Intent.java#Intent.putExtras%28android.os.Bundle%29