# What is faster? One intent.putExtras(Bundle with Strings) or many intent.putExtra(String)?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, bundle

What is faster? Adding a bunch of string values to a `bundle` and then adding that to an `intent`? Or just adding the values to an `intent` using `intent.putExtra()`? Or doesn't it make much difference?

A Google search gave me tutorials, but not much of an answer. Just asking out of curiosity, wondering if it would affect performance to use one or the other. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900266/intent-putextrastring-bundle-vs-intent-putextrabundle) got close, but does not answer what I would like to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating `Bundle` on your own and then adding that to an intent should be faster.

According to the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/content/Intent.java#Intent.putExtra%28java.lang.String,boolean%29), `Intent.putExtra(String, String)` method looks like this:

```
public Intent putExtra(String name, String value) {
    if (mExtras == null) {
        mExtras = new Bundle();
    }
    mExtras.putString(name, value);
    return this;
}
```

So, it will always check at first if `Bundle mExtras` was already created. That's why it's probably a bit slower with big sequence of String additions. `Intent.putExtras(Bundle)` looks like this:

```
public Intent putExtras(Bundle extras) {
    if (mExtras == null) {
        mExtras = new Bundle();
    }
    mExtras.putAll(extras);
    return this;
}
```

So, it will check `if (mExtras == null)` only once and later add all the values to the internal `Bundle mExtras` with `Bundle.putAll()`:

```
public void putAll(Bundle map) {
     unparcel();
     map.unparcel();
     mMap.putAll(map.mMap);

     // fd state is now known if and only if both bundles already knew
     mHasFds |= map.mHasFds;
     mFdsKnown = mFdsKnown && map.mFdsKnown;
 }
```

`Bundle` is backed up by a `Map` (`HashMap` to be precise), so adding all Strings at once to this map should be also faster than adding Strings one by one.

Comment: Thanks, was using bundles from the start anyways, just wondered if it could be done better.

Comment: +1, so adding numerous amounts of string values using just `intent.putExtra()` would have it check for a bundle each time, but just adding one bundle would cause the check to be done only once. Makes sense

Comment: @Lunchbox Yes, exactly. Moreover, one `mExtras.putAll()` should be faster than numerous calls to `mExtras.putString()` (notice  `unparcel()` calls).