# Lifetime of class objects : Java

Tags: java, android, class, static, object-lifetime

My knowledge about the lifetime of Java variables and class objects is limited and hence I am asking this question. I know we can not create static classes in java. Referring to questions on SO, I know that only nested classes in Java can be static.

My requirement: I have an android application with different activities. In one activity, I am asking for user details like username and other preferences and I want these to be accessible from other activities also. I have a class with different class members that store/retrieve these values (using setters/getters).

```
public class ClassTest {

public int x;
String a;

/**
 * @return the a
 */
public String getA() {
    return a;
}
/**
 * @param a the a to set
 */
public void setA(String a) {
    this.a = a;
}

/**
 * @return the x
 */
public int getX() {
    return x;
}

/**
 * @param x the x to set
 */
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
}
```

However, when I want to access the value of these variables from another activity, I create an object of this class and there is my problem- all the class members are now initialised again and the stored values are gone!

```
ClassTest object=new ClassTest();
object.setA("foo bar");
```

Using the object in another activity, I create a new object of the class:

```
ClassTest object=new ClassTest();
```

and there! The values are gone!

One thing I can do is save these in properties file and read them whenever I want but I wish there is a way I can do this using the class object.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this are welcome!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "The values are gone!" Well yes, because it's a different object... There are ways of passing values between activities in Android. You should read up on them. But you definitely *shouldn't* expect instance variables to be shared by separate instances of objects - that would defeat the point of having separate instances!

Answer (score 1):

That is why we have

```
intent.putExtra("classTestObject", object);
```

You dont have to create Object instance again in each activity. Just pass the reference.

Comment: This can maybe help in one application launch but cannot work for multiple launches. In that case, the users will have to enter their details in every launch of the application.

Comment: Obviously you cannot expect the data to persist when activity is destroyed unless of course you use some persistence storage or using Single Sign on.

Answer (score 1):

The values would be gone, because you're creating a `new` instance of the Class Object.

You should create a `Bundle` and use its value.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
String data = "Love for all, Hatred for none!";
//Create the bundle
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//Add your data to bundle
bundle.putString("something", data);  
//Add the bundle to the intent
i.putExtras(bundle);
```

We have: [Intent.putExtra(String,Bundle) vs Intent.putExtra(Bundle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900266/intent-putextrastring-bundle-vs-intent-putextrabundle) and [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) to help you get started

#### To Save data even after `.onDestroy()`

To save the data after the app is destoryed or closed totally, you need to save the Application state or data in the System. You can use SQLite database provided by the Android OS.

Once the application is closed, the `onCreate()` method would always create new objects. It doesn't save any objects in itself. You would be required to save the data in the File System, using a `.txt` file as you're saying. Or by saving the UserName and Password encrypted inside the SQLite databases.

Comment: Passing class object among different activities is not my objective. Maybe I didn't specify that in the question. The problem is that I want the details to be saved persistently across several launches. I should maybe use shared preferences for the same.

Comment: @Neha, yeah I was feeling you meant it this way, but .. didn't bother writing it. Sorry, I've now updated the answer.

Comment: I tried saving the values to config.properties file but I am not able to write data to it. I will try the SQLite approach and get back to you. Thanks for the approach :)

Comment: Just for info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html here you go! :) @Neha...